# Unexpected performance in Numpy from multiplying by 1

Tags: python, performance, numpy

*Tested on Python 3.7.9 64-bit on Windows and Numpy 1.19.5*

This is a pretty simple but confusing one.

Consider I get myself a pretty large array of shape `(10000, 16)`.

```py
import time
import numpy as np

arr = np.random.random((10000, 16))
```

Now I want to take the dot product of each of the rows with each of the other rows. To do that, I multiply the array by itself transposed. The resultant array will have a size of `(10000, 10000)`. This is a pretty expensive operation and I don't expect it to be quick. Let's time it.

```py
def measure(func):
    start = time.time()
    func()
    print(time.time() - start)
```

```py
>>> measure(lambda: arr * arr.T)
0.875575065612793
```

No surprises here. As performant as Numpy is, it still takes almost a whole second to compute the result.

But what if...

```py
>>> measure(lambda: arr * 1 @ arr.T)
0.4331023693084717
```

Somehow multiplying the matrix by `1` before performing the matrix multiplication has sped up calculations.

From testing, this also holds if `arr` is of other data-types.

```py
>>> arr = arr.astype('float32')
>>> measure(lambda: arr @ arr.T)
0.6592690944671631
>>> measure(lambda: arr * 1 @ arr.T)
0.22941327095031738
```

We can see that they are indeed computing the same result.

```py
>>> np.max(np.abs(arr @ arr.T - arr * 1 @ arr.T))
1.9073486e-06
```

Does multiplying the array by `1` (or any other scalar) give it some superpower? We can test it.

```py
>>> arr_times_1 = arr * 1
>>> measure(lambda: arr_times_1 @ arr.T)
0.23055601119995117
```

Looks like it does. Does it somehow change the array? (The answer is no.)

```py
>>> np.max(np.abs(arr - arr_times_1))
0.0
```

Can we "capture" this superpower?

```py
>>> arr_copy_1 = arr_times_1.copy()
>>> arr_copy_2 = np.array(arr_times_1)
>>> measure(lambda: arr_copy_1 @ arr.T)
0.2252507209777832
>>> measure(lambda: arr_copy_2 @ arr.T)
0.22612690925598145
```

Seems like we can. So is something wrong with the array that `np.random.random` gave us?

```py
>>> arr_copy_3 = np.array(arr)
>>> measure(lambda: arr_copy_2 @ arr.T)
0.2222919464111328
```

This result certainly supports that theory.

```py
>>> arr_copy_4 = arr.copy()
>>> measure(lambda: arr_copy_4 @ arr.T)
0.23076415061950684
```

Even merely calling `copy()` on the original array seems to fix the issue. So what could be the issue?

```py
>>> arr.flags
  C_CONTIGUOUS : True
  F_CONTIGUOUS : False
  OWNDATA : True
  WRITEABLE : True
  ALIGNED : True
  WRITEBACKIFCOPY : False
  UPDATEIFCOPY : False

>>> arr_times_1.flags
  C_CONTIGUOUS : True
  F_CONTIGUOUS : False
  OWNDATA : True
  WRITEABLE : True
  ALIGNED : True
  WRITEBACKIFCOPY : False
  UPDATEIFCOPY : False
```

Something wrong with the binary data?

```py
>>> arr_bytes = arr.tobytes()
>>> arr_times_1_bytes = arr_times_1.tobytes()
>>> arr_bytes == arr_times_1_bytes
True
```

No differences.

Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the slowdown is being caused because the arrays being multiplied shared the same memory, and that multiplying the array by `1` created a separate array in memory.

If we do

```py
>>> measure(lambda: arr_times_1 @ arr_times_1.T)
0.6356322765350342
```

We again observe the degenerate case. The trick therefore is to simply

```py
>>> measure(lambda: arr.copy() @ arr.T)
0.2263638973236084
```

Comment: But if `arr` was more square (e.g. (1000,1000)), the `arr@arr.T` is faster.  In other SO we found that `matmul` can choose to use an alternative calculation that supposedly takes advantage of the shared memory of the transpose.  But apparently with your very-rectangular array, that isn't the optimal choice.

Comment: I haven't found this other SO question. Can you link?

Answer (score 0):

*not an answer*

Quite interesting question, the same behaviour on linux

```
#py38 np.__version__ == 1.18.4


%timeit arr @ arr.T
948 ms ± 62.2 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

%timeit arr*1 @ arr.T
707 ms ± 54.1 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

%timeit  arr.copy()  @ arr.T
668 ms ± 22.6 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

%timeit  arr  @ arr.T
945 ms ± 73.8 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```